# После завершения программы с массивами выходит в конце не понятное число

Tags: массивы, c, visual-studio

Программа выполняется правильно, но число в конце просто убивает, как его убрать?
http://pastebin.com/g6J2GnU8

Comment: `printf("%d", a[20]);`  
В массиве нет двадцатого элемента (он начинается с нуля, поэтому полседний элемент девятнадцатый), и эта конструкция не нужна, она использует память, лежащую вне массива.

Comment: спасибо. без этой конструкции программа не меняет 2 последних элемента т.е 20 и 19

Comment: @himiko, эта конструкция вообще ничего не меняет, только выводит

Comment: Не вдаваясь сильно в логику кода:

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != a[i + 1] && i%2==0)
        {
            temp = a[i];

 Вы сравниваете 20-й элемент массива с 21 несуществующим, нужно изменить условие цикла на:

    for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)

Comment: да, я уже поняла и исправила) благодарю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
        int i, temp;
        int a[20];
        for (i = 0; i <20; i++)
        {
                printf("massiv[%d] = ", i);
                scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 20; i+=2)
        {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
                printf("%d %d ", a[i], a[i+1]);
        }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: идеально!) большое спасибо за помощь:)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <locale.h>
```

Кто все эти люди? Реально нужен только stdio. Запомни, Visual Studio - это отшень плёхо.

Переменная temp нужна только во втором цикле, а объявлена перед первым. Это отшень плёхо.

```
system("pause");
```

И не надо смешивать две задачи в одном куске кода. Сначала меняем, потом выводим.

```
for( i = 0; i < 20; ) {
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[++i];
    a[i++] = temp;
}

for( i = 0; i < 20; ++i ) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: @VadimTukaev, я еще раз попрошу не поднимать старые вопросы.

Comment: Честно говоря, просто не обращаю внимания на дату. Мне всегда казалось, что правильный ответ ценен сам по себе. Допустим, у кого-то возникнет такая же задача и он нагуглит эту страницу.

P.S. Сейчас посмотрел - вопрос от 28 марта. Меньше месяца назад - это тоже старый вопрос? А сколько вопрос считается новым, полчаса?

Comment: @VadimTukaev

> А са это йа пуду пить тибя толстый шелесный палка. Как это по-рюски? Йа-йа, льом, льом!

Вот это вот гуглить будут?

Comment: Это надо не гуглить, это надо делать.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, слушайте, ну честно, у нас тут так не принято - поднимать отвеченные/прошлогодние вопросы и пытаться задеть собеседника. Цель сообщества - не ответить на максимальное количество вопросов, а поддерживать этот, эм, поток вопросов в сбалансированном состоянии.

Comment: Я постараюсь. Про прошлогодние вопросы я уже всё понял. А что я кого-то задевал, так я не хотел. Это у меня юмор такой специфический.

Comment: @Fike, про старые вопросы, это как-то тоже... не совсем правильно. 

Я понимаю, что разом вылезло большое их количество, но если у человека появился  нетривиальный (или просто отличающийся от уже данных) ответ, то почему бы его не привести?